# How much of the fact narrated in The Great Beauty really happens?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-great-beauty

The Oscar winning [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2358891/) *The Great Beauty* is about Jep Gambardella, a critic, journalist and writer and his empty life in a (I would say) almost surreal Rome.

What I didn't understand is how much of what is narrated is real and how much happens in Jep's mind.

Can anyone enlighten me?